# inheritance from within a namespace error

Tags: c++, inheritance, namespaces, point-cloud-library

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <pcl/recognition/ransac_based/model_library.h>
#include <pcl/common/common.h>
#include <pcl/features/shot.h>


namespace pcl
{
    class LSDPointPairModelLibrary : public ModelLibrary
    { ... }
}
```

I am getting the error:
`expected class-name before '{' token`

I also tried qualifying the superclass like so: `pcl::recognition::ModelLibrary` but I get the error `pcl::recognition` has not been declared

Comment: Have you tried recognition::ModelLibrary? What is the exact namespace the ModelLibrary class is inside?

Comment: Is this code #included somehow in model_library.h ? Oftentimes this can happen when there are circular include references

Comment: @MatteoItalia: what do you mean?

Comment: I think he is talking about the drug

Comment: Sounds like a comment for removal...

Comment: is the pcl a valid namespace inside the library?

Comment: problem solved.  It seems I had a wrong cmake run that was causing the namespaces to mess up.

Answer (score 0):

Atn least you must provide the sub-namespace `recognition`, but `pcl::recognition` should also work. Did you not forget the semicolon at the end of the class definition? You could try `::pcl::recognition::ModelLibrary` to make sure you start from the top level namespace.